# Como Deshabilitar el scroll en un componente TvertScrollBox en Delphi?

Tags: delphi, scroll

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para dispositivos IOS y Android en Delphi, Rad Studio XE10.1 Berlin, y tengo un problema.

En un formulario, tengo un `TvertScrollbox`, y dentro de el muchos componentes para visualizar, y uno de ellos es un `Tlistview`.

El problema es, cuando hago un **scroll** en el `Tlistview`, porque hay mas datos de los que muestra, también hace un scroll en el `TvertScrollbox`, con lo que al final, es imposible visualizar los datos correctamente.

¿Hay alguna manera de deshabilitar el **scroll** temporalmente del `VertsCrollbox`, y luego habilitarselo de nuevo?

Comment: sería bueno que colocases el código, para poder ayudarte

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura No te puedo poner codigo, es cosa de diseño, creo. A ver si me explico mejor: un TvertScrollbox y dentro un Tlistview. En ejecucion hago un scroll en el Tlistview para ver todos los items y tambien se mueve el TvertScrollbox, ¿se puede hacer que mientras este visualizando los items del Tlistview, no se mueva el TvertScrollbox? esa es mi duda.

Comment: @elcharlie, podrías añadir un pantallazo de tu form en tiempo de diseño. ¿cómo estás _haciendo scroll_ en el TListView? ¿con un gesto?

Comment: @jachguate Sí, el scroll lo hago con un gesto, desde un dispositivo IOS deslizando el dedo para arriba o abajo, para mirar los items. Lo del pantallazo, cuando pueda lo subo, tengo que hacerlo en un proyecto basico de pruebas, porque no se puede ver datos reales, ya sabes.